# android webkit onclick event not firing in select list

Tags: javascript, android, html, webkit, onclick

Hi i have this in a html page android(2.1) webkit

```
    <SELECT  id="my_id"  onclick="my_click();" >    </SELECT>
```

If you click on the combo box an empty list is displayed on android emulator.

I do not want to display a empty list , if its empty. I want to intercept this in the on click event. The onclick event is not firing. The onchange event is working.  only the onchange event fires , onmousedown, onmouseup etc don't fire.

This works in chrome and in iphone webkit ..

anyideas?
mike

Comment: Maybe you should retag your question, this is quite a Javascript question.

Comment: we have moved away from select lists on the web kit. Great for the user experience..however.. different behaviors even in the same plaform family ipad/iphone (let alone android) ..avoid..select lists..we are now  dynamically creating div with buttons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you can capture the onclick event for a select list, since that event only actually fires once an option is selected (in Android's webkit, that is...iPhone and Chrome webkit engines don't process the event the same way). However, you could take another route; the idea is to hide the list if it's empty, so do something like this to count the number of options:

```
$('#my_id option').size();
```

...then set `display:none` if the returned value is less than 1.

Comment: Thanks @chris i was leaning that way. I'm just maintaining someone elses code and it could be a big port from iphone to android the way its currently written.